# How to enable query execution time in snappydata shell?

Tags: shell, snappydata

I want to know query execution time in snappy data. Is there any option which shows time in seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `elapsedtime on;` on snappy shell shows time elapsed in miliseconds.